# Как подкючить библиотеку [muParser] к Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, library

Мне нужно будет подключить библиотеку [muParser](https://beltoforion.de/article.php?a=muparser&s=idPageTop#idPageTop) ([GitHub](https://github.com/beltoforion/muparser/releases)) к Qt Creator.

Проблема в том, что я не до конца понимаю, как это сделать, потому что:

1. Её нужно устанавливать через консоль через файл configure (на
   Linux).
2. Там содержатся файлы настроек (makefiles).

Если бы там были просто хэдеры и исходники, то это одно, а тут я не знаю. Никогда этого не делал. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать, где об этом можно подробно прочитать?

Мне нужно собрать проект так, чтобы на другом устройстве его можно было скомпилировать из проекта без дополнительных установок (ну то есть из Qt Creator).

Comment: Подпишусь ка на вопрос. Так то тоже интересно. Но я не пользуюсь qt. Ну вам скорее всего надо сделать ./configure, потом make и найти библиотеки *.so. И их добавить в проект qt. Я понял как это делается в cmake, но не знаю как это делается в qmake.

Comment: в *.pro указать INCLUDUPATH += /path_to_incl и LIBS+= -L/path_so -llib

Comment: @xverizex, в Qt можно CMake выбрать при создании проекта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть разные вариант.

Тот, который описан  в **Install.txt** используется для непосредственно сборки. По этой инструкции ты можешь собрать файлы .so, взять их и папку include. 
В своём CMakeList.txt указываешь:

```
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC <путь до папки include>)
link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} <Путь до папки с библиотеками>)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC muParserProject)
```

Только **не делай** во этого: `make install`, есть лучшие способы установки пакетов. Почитай про checkinstall или похожее.

**Второй вариант** - добавить папку в проект и в CMakeList.txt добавить `add_subdirectory(muParserProject)`

Конечно это всё, если ты используешь cmake для сборки. Если нет (qmake или что-то другое), то варианты примерно похожие - *(1)* собрать и добавить пути до include и библиотек (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718447/adding-external-library-into-qt-creator-project) или *(2)* добавить в проект (возможно придётся переписать CMakeList.txt в формате твоего сборщика) чтобы собирался во время сборки твоего проекта.

Comment: То есть, проще будет поддиректорией воспользоваться? А куда нужно поместить dll/so? И можно ли будет после этого статически скомпилировать проект?

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον, да, проще будет собрать muParser (если linux, то можно сделать установочный deb, для твоей системы, который распихает всё по стандартным путям для .h и .so, либо скопировать собранные файлы куда-либо и добавить в пути для поиска, например, как написано выше в cmake или ldconfig.

Comment: Если windows, то достаточно положить dll в папку с твоей собранной программой или добавить путь до библиотек в PATH). Ещё как вариант, если есть возможность собрать muParser как статическую библиотеку (.lib, .a), тогда при переносе на другие машины не придётся тащить сами библиотеки muParser, они будут уже в скомпилированном файле

Comment: а с dll нельзя скомпилировать статически? Или, если я скомпилирую динамически, то нужно будет просто dll положить в папку с exe?

Comment: Просто положи собранные dll рядом с exe или собирай не dll, а .lib

Comment: А имеет ли значение компилятор при сборке библиотеки? Просто в Qt есть т.н. "комплекты" для каждого компилятора. И я не очень понимаю, как они влияют (или не влияют на сборку). Можно ли просто скинуть исходный код проекта с ГитХаба (в котором уже содержится файл CMakeLists.txt) в подпроект, и каким-то образом компилировать проект целиком, без dll/so и lib/a?

Comment: Комплект - это совокупность настроек компилятора, системы сборки, библиотек Qt и других. Они влияют на сборку так, что тут выбирается версия библиотек Qt, версия компилятора, переменные среды и т.д. Можно просто стянуть проект и открыть через QtCreator файл CMakeLists.txt и потом собрать как обычный проект. Подпроект - это, если у тебя уже есть свой проект, в который ты хочешь добавить код, который будет собираться при сборке твоего проекта. Там можешь уже перенастроить пути сборки или какие-то ещё параметры

Comment: Я наконец-то подключил её. Подправил немного твой ответ в части команд CMake.

Answer (score -1):

Для подключения к проекту qmake библиотеки, как набора исходников, распакуйте .zip и впишите в .pro файл:

```
SOURCES      *= D:/libs/muparser-2.2.6.1/src/*.cpp
HEADERS      *= D:/libs/muparser-2.2.6.1/include/*.h
INCLUDEPATH  *= D:/libs/muparser-2.2.6.1/include
DEFINES *= MUPARSER_STATIC
```

Второй вариант - собрать .dll или .lib и подключать уже их. Понадобится CMake.
Собрать можно примерно такой командой (указав свой компилятор и путь к папке, куда ты хочешь установить библиотеку):

```
cmake -LAH -G "Visual Studio 14 2015" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=D:/libs/muparser
cmake --build . --config Release --target install
```

После сборки и установки, в своем .pro файле указываешь:

```
INCLUDEPATH  *= D:/libs/muparser/include
LIBS *= D:/libs/muparser/lib/muparser.lib
```

Также, перед запуском в переменную окружения PATH нужно будет добавить D:\libs\muparser\bin чтобы программа могла найти muparser.dll (либо скопировать muparser.dll в папку со своим исполняемым файлом).